# How do I delete key/value pair in list of dictionaries pandas env

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to run applymap() re data in code snippet.

I tried to discard the key "P" from the list with this code:
`d = [i for i in data if not (i['P'] == 5.5|4.5)],`
And
I get:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

**goal:** Is to eliminate key "P" and its values and also eliminate the 'empty list' before I can applymap()

```
**Desired Result** after running applymap() to ['A']

0     2.165\n1.675
1     1.895\n1.888
2     2.085\n1.73
3     2.275\n1.616
4     1.685\n1.65
5     2.448\n2.085.....

However, with 'P' key & empty [] this is not possible hence.
```

How can I do this in a Pandas/DataFrame environment?

```
data = 
    [[{'A': 2.165, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.675, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [{'A': 1.895, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.888, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [{'A': 2.085, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.73, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [{'A': 2.275, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.616, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [{'A': 1.685, 'G': 15, 'P': 5.5, 'T': 12},
    {'A': 1.65, 'G': 62, 'P': 4.5, 'T': 13}],
    [{'A': 2.448, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.54, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [{'A': 2.085, 'G': 19, 'T': 180}, {'A': 1.73, 'G': 19, 'T': 181}],
    [],
    ]
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: @Psidom I've added expected output. Hopefully this is helpful

Comment: Do you eventually want to have a data frame ? with columns `A`, `G`, `T` ?

Comment: @Psidom Just with column 'A' in this instance

Comment: Then why not iterating through the list and get key `A`. Why do you have to worry about key `P`. `['\n'.join(str(e['A']) for e in row if 'A' in e) for row in data]`?

Comment: is `data` your input data source?

Comment: @Psidom TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Corrected. Try the edited one

Comment: @Joe Ferndz Input source is a API but have since stored the data in a variable named 'data'; hope I make sense

Comment: @Psidom Almost there with your solution! Can the results be just string with no list enclosing? '2.165\n1.675... without ['2.165\n1.675] . Also what's your remedy to discard the empty list ...I put it at the end?

Comment: To discard empty list, you can add an if in the outer for loop: `['\n'.join(str(e['A']) for e in row if 'A' in e) for row in data if row]`. I think the results are already string. Do you want the whole result to be a string as well ?

Comment: @Psidom My bad...the solution is perfect for what I need. Thank you, Can I accept the solution?

Comment: Sure. Posted an answer below -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can use a list comprehension combined with a filter for what you need:

```
['\n'.join(str(e['A']) for e in row if 'A' in e) for row in data if row]

# ['2.165\n1.675', 
#  '1.895\n1.888', 
#  '2.085\n1.73', 
#  '2.275\n1.616', 
#  '1.685\n1.65', 
#  '2.448\n1.54', 
#  '2.085\n1.73']
```